# Receive Error on requests.post() python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am going to send an HTTP post request by python, originally the request is for an android application. I can generate the post request with Postman extension of Chrome and send it but with python, I receive the following error.

Code:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; Redmi Note 2 MIUI/V9.6.2.0.LHMMIFD)'}
r = requests.post("http://IP:PORT/PATH", data={'KEY': 'VALUE'}, headers=headers)
```

Error:

```
File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
  chunked=chunked)
File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
  six.raise_from(e, None)
File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
  httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
  response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
  version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
  line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
  return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Are you sure the address should be `http` and not `https`?

Comment: @mrangry777, Yes I am sure it is http.